# Executing oracle package with recordtype input param throws exception in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I am stuck on an issue for past few days.The issue is detailed below:

There are 15 input params (of type `int` and `varchar`), 1 record type `param` and 5 output `params` for this oracle package.

It was observed that while passing record type parameter to the package this exception is thrown,work fine with those packages with out record type `param`.

```
Exception Thrown:-Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type
'System.Array'. Stack Trace:- at
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.SetStatus(Int32 arraySize) at
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.ResetCtx(Int32 arraySize) at
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind(OracleConnection
conn, IntPtr errCtx, Int32 arraySize) at
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at
POC_App.DataformatConverter.ExecuteCreateSOPackage()
```

What I have tried:

```
 public static void ExecuteCreateSOPackage()
    { 
    string constr = EstablishDBConnection();
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("APPS.XX_OM_CREATE_SO_TEST.create_sale_orders", con);

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.BindByName = true;
    cmd.ArrayBindCount = 100;
    OracleParameter retVal = new OracleParameter("retVal", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
    retVal.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(retVal);

    OracleParameter paramPersonId = setInputParameters("p_person_id", OracleDbType.Int32, 0);
    paramPersonId.Value = 31842;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramPersonId);

<likewise 14 more input params >
---------------------------------


    //Record type parameter..
    OracleParameter p_so_lines_tab = new OracleParameter();
    p_so_lines_tab.ParameterName = "p_so_lines_tab";
    p_so_lines_tab.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2;
    p_so_lines_tab.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
    p_so_lines_tab.Size = 3;
    p_so_lines_tab.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

    OracleParameter P_SO_LINES_TAB_ITEM = new OracleParameter();
    P_SO_LINES_TAB_ITEM.ParameterName = "p_so_lines_tab_item";
    P_SO_LINES_TAB_ITEM.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2;
    P_SO_LINES_TAB_ITEM.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
    P_SO_LINES_TAB_ITEM.Size = 1000;
    P_SO_LINES_TAB_ITEM.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

    OracleParameter QUANTITY = new OracleParameter();
    QUANTITY.ParameterName = "quantity";
    QUANTITY.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32; 
    QUANTITY.Value = 1;


    OracleParameter QUANTITY_UOM = new OracleParameter();
    QUANTITY_UOM.ParameterName = "quantity_uom";
    QUANTITY_UOM.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
    QUANTITY_UOM.Value = "Ea";

    OracleParameter ITEM_ID = new OracleParameter();
    ITEM_ID.ParameterName = "item_id";
    ITEM_ID.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32; 
    ITEM_ID.Value = 162744;

    OracleParameter PROMISE_DATE = new OracleParameter();
    PROMISE_DATE.ParameterName = "promise_date";
    PROMISE_DATE.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date; 
    PROMISE_DATE.Value = "2016-04-01T08:58:50.649Z";

    OracleParameter SCHEDULE_SHIP_DATE = new OracleParameter();
    SCHEDULE_SHIP_DATE.ParameterName = "schedule_ship_date";
    SCHEDULE_SHIP_DATE.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date; 
    SCHEDULE_SHIP_DATE.Value = "2016-04-01T08:58:50.649Z";

    OracleParameter CURRENCY_CODE = new OracleParameter();
    CURRENCY_CODE.ParameterName = "currency_code";
    CURRENCY_CODE.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
    CURRENCY_CODE.Value = "USD";

    OracleParameter UNIT_SELLING_PRICE = new OracleParameter();
    UNIT_SELLING_PRICE.ParameterName = "unit_selling_price";
    UNIT_SELLING_PRICE.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32; 
    UNIT_SELLING_PRICE.Value = 200;


    OracleParameter SALESREP_ID = new OracleParameter(); 
    SALESREP_ID.ParameterName = "salesrep_id";
    SALESREP_ID.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32; 
    SALESREP_ID.Value = 1412;


    P_SO_LINES_TAB_ITEM.Value = new object[] { QUANTITY, QUANTITY_UOM, ITEM_ID, PROMISE_DATE, SCHEDULE_SHIP_DATE, CURRENCY_CODE, UNIT_SELLING_PRICE, SALESREP_ID };

    //Adding to outer most collection
    p_so_lines_tab.Value = P_SO_LINES_TAB_ITEM;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p_so_lines_tab);


    cmd.Parameters.Add("x_time_stamp", OracleDbType.TimeStamp, ParameterDirection.Output);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("x_order_header_id", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("x_order_number", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("x_return_code", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("x_return_msg", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);


    try
    {
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
    string str = exp.StackTrace.ToString();
    string msg = exp.Message.ToString();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Value of parameter is another parameter?        p_so_lines_tab.Value = P_SO_LINES_TAB_ITEM;

Comment: Yes ,p_so_lines_tab.Value should hold the collection of P_SO_LINES_TAB_ITEM,which intern consists of params of varchar and int32 types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution for my problem .We can pass a collection of data by setting the oracle.Dbtype as NVarchar as shown below.

```
var commandObject = new OracleCommand
                        {
                            Connection = con,
                            CommandText = "Your Packge Name",
                            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                        };


commandObject.Connection.Open();    
commandObject.Parameters.Add("param1", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = some int value;
commandObject.Parameters.Add("param2", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = some int value;
commandObject.Parameters.Add("param3", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = some int value;
commandObject.Parameters.Add("p_xml_type", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value =some collection
commandObject.Parameters.Add("param returncode", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 200).Direction = "some string value";
commandObject.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The collection being set is in xml format of type string and in the oracle package the parameter has been defined as shown below.

```
 p_xml_type        IN CLOB
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this OracleParameter:

```
OracleParameter P_SO_LINES_TAB_ITEM = new OracleParameter();
P_SO_LINES_TAB_ITEM.ParameterName = "p_so_lines_tab_item";
P_SO_LINES_TAB_ITEM.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2;
P_SO_LINES_TAB_ITEM.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
P_SO_LINES_TAB_ITEM.Size = 1000;
P_SO_LINES_TAB_ITEM.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
```

Value of `P_SO_LINES_TAB_ITEM` must be a list of plain text (i.e. `NVARCHAR2` as you declared by property `OracleDbType`). However, you try to use a list of `OracleParameter` objects.

```
P_SO_LINES_TAB_ITEM.Value = new object[] { QUANTITY, QUANTITY_UOM, ITEM_ID, PROMISE_DATE, SCHEDULE_SHIP_DATE, CURRENCY_CODE, UNIT_SELLING_PRICE, SALESREP_ID };
```

This is not possible, you cannot make nested parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,In such a scenario what is the best way to pass nested parameters to oracle package.Also can you please let me know how to deal with oracle  record type parameters from .net

Comment: You cannot use record types. Return a Recursor or translate to Xml document